# Find the Mistake to this Problem

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $(a,b)$ be an open interval of real numbers and let $c \in (a,b)$. Describe an open interval $I$ centered at $c$ such that $I \subseteq (a,b)$.

Here is the proposed solution to the problem:

Let $\epsilon >0$ be the radius of an interval I centered at a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $a < c-\epsilon$ and $c+\epsilon < b$. Then

$$a<c-\epsilon < c < c+\epsilon < b$$

So $I \subseteq (a,b)$, as desired.

Comment: The answer is incomplete.  Not *wrong* per se but not correct either.  The problem is for an arbitrary e you do not know that c-e >= a or that c + e <= d.  You need to chose a specific e so that can be known.

Comment: @fleablood Right. As Faraad pointed out, the argument is circular, because the student assumed that such an $\epsilon$ existed (albeit an arbitrary $\epsilon$), which is what needs to be proved.

Comment: But it's very easy to find an epsilon *with restrictions* that such is true (simply chose e < min b-c,c-a).  On rereading his answer, I'm a bit more appalled that he introduced e as the radius of a pre-existing interval.  Obviously if such an interval is what's to be proven you can't refer to it.  And this is basically saying "choose an interval that works and it will work".  On the other hand saying "choose e such that c-e > a and c+e < b" is not as egregious.  Not quite.  But "e<c-a and e <d-c" is probably acceptable.

Comment: It's not so much circular as granular.  "Prove a purple rock eater exist.  Proof: let x be a purple rock eater.  Color (x)= purple and diet (x)= rocks so this will be the purple rock eater you desire"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His answer is wrong in that he stated "let $\epsilon $ be the radius of an interval centered at c" implying such an interval exists.  Then he claims "such that" giving conditions assuming what is to be proven.

BUT

It *could* have worked as this:

"Intervals centered a $c $ of every possible radii exist (by simply taking the interval $(c-r,c+r)$ where $r $ is the desired radius).  Simply choose an $r = \epsilon $ such that $a \le c-\epsilon <c < c+\epsilon < b $" would *maybe* be acceptable to some instructors.

It would depend on how obvious the statement "for $a < c, \exists \epsilon s.t. a < c- \epsilon <c $" would be considered.

Well... we've exhausted this subject, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Easy route: Let $c \in (a,b)$ and take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}  \cdot \textrm{min}\{|c-a|,|c-b|\}$. Then just define $I = (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution that I have to this problem, but I don't want the solution to this problem. I would like to know if there are any problems with the given solution in my post.

Comment: There is a big difference with this solution. You can also take $\epsilon$ to be the min of that set divided by 2, then it is not arbitrary.

Comment: No, I'm saying that the solution I have to this problem is not what I have posted. What I have posted was given to me by someone else for verification, but I have a gut feeling that it is wrong, so I need confirmation as to whether the solution that was given to me is correct or not. What is unclear about what I am asking?

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire: Whoa, chill man I'm trying to help you. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Off topic: You could take $\epsilon = \min{c-a,b-c}$, which is simpler.

Comment: No one's being hostile, man.

Comment: That solution assumes that such an epsilon exists, which is what the person needs to prove. If they have taken topology of any sorts, a set is open if for every point in it, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of said point which is contained in the original open set. In that case, one can assert that such an $\epsilon$ exists.

Comment: There it is! I see that now. Thank you, kind sir.

Comment: Okay cool, and yes the off topic $\epsilon$ will work.

Answer (score 1):

How about $I=\{c\}=[c,c]$? Nowhere do you require $I$ to be open, or to have nonempty interior. You can't say it isn't centered at $c$, either.

This is a dumb answer, but, well, it's a poorly worded question.

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem was not faithfully written as presented in the text. The interval $I$ is required to be open.

Comment: I'm being intentionally obtuse. My point is that these details are extremely important to the question. If you don't see them clearly, you will have trouble answering because you aren't really understanding what is being asked. Don't just gloss over the words in the question, try to ask yourself what the importance of each word is. You can see from all of these answers and comments that they must be important.